# R: How to Count All Character Values Separated By Commas In A Column?

Tags: r, count, character

Below is a couple of rows of some test data I am using. I am wanting to count the frequency of 
all the characters in the ICD10Code column which are separated by columns. From the segment of 
code below, I used group_by because every "PatientId" value had duplicates in that column but had 
unique values in other columns. How can I go about counting the frequency of all character values?

```
PatientId ReferralSource     NextAppt   Age InsuranceName            ICD10Code
1584      St Francis         Y       34 SLIDING FEE SCHEDULE     M5136, N809, R51, Z6831  
2655      Piedmont Hospital  Y       60 Medicaid-GA (Medicaid)   E119, E782, I10, L729, R809
```

[image]

The result would look something like this below.

```
M5136=1
N809=1
R51=1
```

Being fairly new to R, I tried this segment of code found in Stack (sapply) and just produced a 
total count for each row specific row.

```
data.id <- data.1 %>% group_by(PatientId) %>%  
      summarise(ReferralSource=first(ReferralSource),NextAppt=first(NextAppt),
      Age=max(Age),InsuranceName=toString(unique(InsuranceName)),
      ICD10Code=toString(unique(ICD10Code)))
sapply(strsplit(data.id$ICD10Code,","),FUN=function(x){length(x[x!="Null"])})
```

That produced the total count for each row.

```
 [1] 10 17  5 18  6  5  8  7  2  8  3  8 10 14  5  5  9  8 11  5  6  5  9 16  9  4  3  9 18  9 12 
  12 12  2 16  6 10
   [38]  2  2  3  4  9  7 12  5 10 16 13  9  1  6  2  7  9  8  5  5  4  3 11 19  6  4  3  7  8  6 
  10  8  6 16 11  5  9
   [75] 13  5  8  4 10  3  7  5  6  4  3  4  8  7  7  4  5  9  2  6  1 20  3  3  3  4  5  5  7  3 
  12  7 16  1  7  6  3
  [112]  4  2  7  8  4  1  9  3  8  3  8  5  8  2  4  4  8  4  7 10  8  2  4  4  2  9  7  7  5  1  
  8  6 10  9  3 11 10
  [149]  3  6  4  6 13  3  7 11  6  5  4  3  1  4 10 10 10 10 11  2  1  5  4  5  5  5  5  9  5  7  
  7  2 6  7  7  6  5
 [186]  7  8  9
```

Comment: Do you want to calculate number of unique `ICD10Code` for each row  i.e `PatientId` ?

Comment: No, just the whole column for ICDCode10.

Comment: So will this work ? `table(unlist(strsplit(data.1$ICD10Code, ',')))` ?

Comment: @RonakShah when I use that I get this error message: Error in strsplit(data.1$ICD10Code, ",") : non-character argument

Comment: Try `table(unlist(strsplit(as.character(data.1$ICD10Code), ',')))`

Comment: Ah, that makes sense and it worked! With the table that you helped me create, is there an ability plot off of that based upon an if statement as well? For example, If I wanted to plot from the table if value has a certain frequency.

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by that but you can ask a new question for help on plotting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count the frequency of `ICD10Code` in the entire column, we can split the string on comma, `unlist` it and count it with `table`.

```
table(unlist(strsplit(as.character(data.1$ICD10Code), ',')))
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use `separate_rows` on the 'ICD10Code' column (assuming it as `character` class), use that as grouping variable along with 'PatientID' and get the count (`n()`) in `summarise` along with the other variables needed in output as showed in OP's post

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data.1 %>%
      separate_rows(ICD10Code) %>%
      group_by(PatientID, ICD10Code) %>%
      summarise(Count = n(), 
                ReferralSource=first(ReferralSource),
                NextAppt=first(NextAppt),       
                Age=max(Age),
                InsuranceName=toString(unique(InsuranceName)))
```

---

If in case the other summary output should be only based on grouping by 'PatientID', use 'Count' also as grouping variable instead of 'ICD10Code'

---

If we want a count only from 'ICD10Code' for each 'PatientID', then just do a `count` after the `separate_rows`

```
data.1 %>%
     select(PatientID, ICD10Code) %>%
     separate_rows(ICD10Code) %>%
     count(PatientID, ICD10Code)
```